# Xcode 13 will not show Preview

Tags: xcode

I have a brand new 21 Macbook Pro with the M1 Pro chip. I installed Xcode from the app store, and I have also installed Xcode beta. I am completely up to date on Monterey as well.

I am building a swift UI app and I cannot get preview to work at all.

I get the following error.

```
== PREVIEW UPDATE ERROR:

    MessageSendFailure: Message send failure for send previewInstances message to agent
    
    ==================================
    
    |  RemoteHumanReadableError
    |  
    |  LoadingError: failed to load library at path "/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Test-gfnknimtrrhvztavjffxvzjvrvmo/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Previews/Test/Intermediates.noindex/Test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Test.build/Objects-normal/arm64/SwiftUIView.2.preview-thunk.dylib": Optional(dlopen(/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Test-gfnknimtrrhvztavjffxvzjvrvmo/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Previews/Test/Intermediates.noindex/Test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Test.build/Objects-normal/arm64/SwiftUIView.2.preview-thunk.dylib, 0x0002): tried: '/Users/brandon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Test-gfnknimtrrhvztavjffxvzjvrvmo/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Previews/Test/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftUIView.2.preview-thunk.dylib' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Test-gfnknimtrrhvztavjffxvzjvrvmo/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Previews/Test/Intermediates.noindex/Test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Test.build/Objects-normal/arm64/SwiftUIView.2.preview-thunk.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Test-gfnknimtrrhvztavjffxvzjvrvmo/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Previews/Test/Intermediates.noindex/Test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Test.build/Objects-normal/arm64/SwiftUIView.2.preview-thunk.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/SwiftUIView.2.preview-thunk.dylib' (no such file))
```

I have tried to reinstall xcode, reboot you name it.

I can get simulator to work...

Any ideas?

Comment: Same issue, MacOS Monterey, XCode 13.3, none of the solutions here worked. Used to work fine on Xcode 12.5. Slap left, slap right Apple!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and found a solution here:
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/691237

I was not signed in to GitHub so as suspected, it does not play a role.

It seems Xcode got in to an invalid state. I suspect that simply disabling and enabling automatic signing would resolve the issue but I also cleared the Container folder for my project as suggested in the post.

Answer (score 4):

Nothing I tried worked, including running:

- `sudo xcodebuild -license` in the terminal
- Deleting derived data
- Sign in again to GitHub
- Restarts

Only when I toggled **Automatically refresh canvas** (Editor > Canvas) I got preview back.
Preview was failing on a new default projects as well.

Comment: Excellent. I was not comfortable in suggestions like "exclude architectures" etc.  This solved my problem. Excited to see the Preview back.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue and resolved it by change Mac's user name to lowercase.
Username->username

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

I had the same problem because I downloaded a GitHub project (an existing `SwiftUI` project) and I didn't create a new `SwiftUI` project from scratch. I notice the `SwiftUI` view doesn't had the `PreviewProvider` `struct` at the bottom:

```swift
struct SwiftUIView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SwiftUIView()
    }
}
```

After adding the `PreviewProvider` `struct`, `Xcode` showed the Preview.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted but it worked for some people like myself who failed to double check PreviewProvider. Thanks